# Use Spring Boot Cloud Config to change application.properties in classpath

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have to change my custom defined spring properties (defined via @ConfigurationProperties beans) during runtime of my Spring Boot application.

Is there any elegant way of doing this using Spring Cloud Config?

I don't want to use an external application.properties in a git repository (as the spring boot application gets shipped to customers and I dont' want to create a git repository for everyone of them).

I just want to access and change the local application.properties (the one in the classpath, located in src/main/resources) file in my Spring container or (if thats not possible) in the Spring Cloud Config Server, which I could embed into my Spring Boot app. Is that possible somehow?

BTW: The goal is to create a visual editor for the customers, so that they can change the application.properties during runtime in their spring boot app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually is possible and in the end quite easy to achieve. It just took me a whole day to get all the information together. Maybe this helps someone:

You basically just need Spring Actuator, but for a certain endpoint, you also need the spring cloud dependency. (to make Post requests to the /env endpoint of Spring Actuator)

To alter your config at runtime, just add the following to your application.properties:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: env,refresh
management.endpoint.env.post.enabled: true //this property is only available when spring cloud is added as dependency to your project
```

If you (like me) don't need the feature of an externalized config, then you also have to add the following (otherwise, your Spring app will not start and throw an error that some config is missing)

```
spring.cloud.config.enabled: false
```

Now, if you send a POST request to /actuator/env endpoint with an object in the HTTP body in the form of {"name":"...", "value":"..."} (name is the name of a config property), then your config gets changed. To check that, you can do a GET request to /actuator/env/[name_of_config_property] and see that your config property has changed. No need to restart your app.

Don't forget to secure the /actuator endpoint in your SecurityConfig if you use a custom one.

It seems to me that you neither need the @RefreshScope annotation at your config classes nor the /actuator/refresh endpoint to "apply" the config changes.

Comment: what you are doing is changing the spring environment, not `application.properties`. you don't need spring-cloud-starter-config, just spring-cloud-starter and you can remove `spring.cloud.config.enabled: false`

Comment: well, that is true. I got that thought yesterday already, that when I restart the application, all the changes are gone. So I still need to find a way to write to application.properties ... Damn!

And thanks for the clarification and hints!

Comment: Nothing in spring boot or cloud modifies application.properties. The closest we come to that is something like jdbc backend for config server or using consul config

Comment: @spencergibb This is true unfortunately. I'm using a combination of spring cloud now (to change the spring environment) and an additional override config file managed by apache commons configuration combined with some custom rest controllers. It works, but it is lots of work. I hope some day it will be easier to change application config at runtime (as well as the underlying config files)

Comment: We have a way to change the application environment at runtime, we'll likely not support changing config files

Comment: Totally understandable. I see that the config files are not supposed to change at runtime. But in my case, it's a business use case. So I'm glad that I found some kind of workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot supports profile based application configuration. Just add `application-<profile>.properties` file. Then just when running the application select a profile depending on the environment making use of `spring.profiles.active`.

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

This will run the application with `application-dev.properties` file (overriding the default `application.properties`, i.e you can just leave the common stuff in the default file and change the rest depending on the env)

On a side note, having a repo for configuration is not a must. You could just place them in the class path and give a `search-location`.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: config-server
  profiles:
    active: native
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          search-locations: classpath:configs/
```

Comment: This does not answer my question. I want to change the application.properties file at runtime using Spring Cloud Config ...

Comment: sorry I kinda missunderstand the question :(

Comment: No it's not possible

Comment: @spencergibb it is ;) Just check out the solution I provided :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what your looking for could be achieved with Spring cloud config and spring cloud bus. It's explained here: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_push_notifications_and_spring_cloud_bus

In summary, any change on configuration sent an event to the spring cloud bus and you can then reload app context or configuration with new properties.